# Critical section in reading data by threads

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, critical-section

I have two different threads (beside main thread).

The first one sends to the main thread PostMessage with data. As a result of receiving the message main thread modifies the corresponding global variables (different types).

Another thread (second one) periodically reads these variables.

Is in this case (in the main thread and the second thread) needing use critical section for safety?

Comment: This really depends on which data to write and to read. If in doubt: use critical section.

Comment: Thank you. I needed answer in general and your answer is enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will be safe if you protect all access to shared variables with a critical section (lock).

However, if the variables are correctly aligned, do not store references, and no more than pointer sized, then you may be able to avoid using a lock.

For example, if you have an integer which contains a count, then you will not need to use a lock. Your writing thread can safely modify and the reading thread will never suffer from tearing. If you had multiple writing threads then you would likely need to use a lock, or an interlocked function.

If your variable is a reference, then you likely need to use a lock. If you have multiple variables that form a compound variable, then again you'll need a lock.

The importance of alignment is that if a variable is misaligned, then the writing of the variable may not be atomic. The variable may be written in two parts. And so the reading thread can read the variable in partially updated state. Always align variables. If you refrain from packing records and classes, your variables will be aligned.

Ultimately I cannot say for sure whether or not your code is safe because you did not show it. A description of code only goes so far. You really should post your code for a question like this.

Comment: Even if a variable could be read/written in one instruction (atomic), thread safety is not guaranteed. Multiple writing threads as you mention needs a lock, also one common scenario is when you have multiple variables, and the implementation needs those to be coherent with each other at all times.

Comment: If variable**s** together are representing some compound state, that state will no longer be safe even if its components are atomic. Also, structured types > Pointer are not atomic.

Comment: @Artik, strings are not atomic

Comment: @LURD Indeed. Hence the use of the word may in my second paragraph. And hence the hedging of bets in the final paragraph.